# How to find all the subsets of an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, set

I need to find all the subsets  of an array using java.For e.g. if we have a set {1,2,3} then i should get 
{},{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{2,3},{1.3},{1,2,3}

Comment: Write a recursive method, to which you can initially pass every element individually, then two at a time and there on.

Comment: Have you tried to code something ?

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala: If you do it that way you need to take care not to emit duplicates.

Comment: @Bathsheba: 

It actually depends on your implementation process. you keep passing values from the first element to the last. DO NOT TRY TO COMBINE WITH PREVIOUS ELEMENTS. 

Secondly, still if you feel there is a probability, keep adding the generated sets to a parent set.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this to avoid needing to recurse the solutions.

```
public static <T> void printCombinations(T[] arr) {
    for(long i = 0, max = 1L << arr.length; i < max; i++) {
        Set<T> ts = new HashSet<>();
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if ((i >> j) != 0)
                ts.add(list.get(j));
        }
        System.out.println(ts);
    }
}
```